# SVG logos not showing up in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, svg

An issue has risen where I am able to see my svg links everywhere aside from chrome. Here is what they are supposed to look like:
[image]

But in chrome it looks like this(don't mind the spider):
[image]

Here is the code that renders them:

```
<div className="medias">
        <div id="contact" className="medias-bar">
          <a className="a-tag" href="https://github.com/nathanhains"><svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" data-prefix="fab" data-icon="github-square" class="svg-inline--fa fa-github-square fa-w-14" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 448 512"><path fill="currentColor" d="M400 32H48C21.5 32 0 53.5 0 80v352c0 26.5 21.5 48 48 48h352c26.5 0 48-21.5 48-48V80c0-26.5-21.5-48-48-48zM277.3 415.7c-8.4 1.5-11.5-3.7-11.5-8 0-5.4 .2-33 .2-55.3 0-15.6-5.2-25.5-11.3-30.7 37-4.1 76-9.2 76-73.1 0-18.2-6.5-27.3-17.1-39 1.7-4.3 7.4-22-1.7-45-13.9-4.3-45.7 17.9-45.7 17.9-13.2-3.7-27.5-5.6-41.6-5.6-14.1 0-28.4 1.9-41.6 5.6 0 0-31.8-22.2-45.7-17.9-9.1 22.9-3.5 40.6-1.7 45-10.6 11.7-15.6 20.8-15.6 39 0 63.6 37.3 69 74.3 73.1-4.8 4.3-9.1 11.7-10.6 22.3-9.5 4.3-33.8 11.7-48.3-13.9-9.1-15.8-25.5-17.1-25.5-17.1-16.2-.2-1.1 10.2-1.1 10.2 10.8 5 18.4 24.2 18.4 24.2 9.7 29.7 56.1 19.7 56.1 19.7 0 13.9 .2 36.5 .2 40.6 0 4.3-3 9.5-11.5 8-66-22.1-112.2-84.9-112.2-158.3 0-91.8 70.2-161.5 162-161.5S388 165.6 388 257.4c.1 73.4-44.7 136.3-110.7 158.3zm-98.1-61.1c-1.9 .4-3.7-.4-3.9-1.7-.2-1.5 1.1-2.8 3-3.2 1.9-.2 3.7 .6 3.9 1.9 .3 1.3-1 2.6-3 3zm-9.5-.9c0 1.3-1.5 2.4-3.5 2.4-2.2 .2-3.7-.9-3.7-2.4 0-1.3 1.5-2.4 3.5-2.4 1.9-.2 3.7 .9 3.7 2.4zm-13.7-1.1c-.4 1.3-2.4 1.9-4.1 1.3-1.9-.4-3.2-1.9-2.8-3.2 .4-1.3 2.4-1.9 4.1-1.5 2 .6 3.3 2.1 2.8 3.4zm-12.3-5.4c-.9 1.1-2.8 .9-4.3-.6-1.5-1.3-1.9-3.2-.9-4.1 .9-1.1 2.8-.9 4.3 .6 1.3 1.3 1.8 3.3 .9 4.1zm-9.1-9.1c-.9 .6-2.6 0-3.7-1.5s-1.1-3.2 0-3.9c1.1-.9 2.8-.2 3.7 1.3 1.1 1.5 1.1 3.3 0 4.1zm-6.5-9.7c-.9 .9-2.4 .4-3.5-.6-1.1-1.3-1.3-2.8-.4-3.5 .9-.9 2.4-.4 3.5 .6 1.1 1.3 1.3 2.8 .4 3.5zm-6.7-7.4c-.4 .9-1.7 1.1-2.8 .4-1.3-.6-1.9-1.7-1.5-2.6 .4-.6 1.5-.9 2.8-.4 1.3 .7 1.9 1.8 1.5 2.6z"></path></svg></a>
          <a className="a-tag" href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/nathanhains/"><svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" data-prefix="fab" data-icon="linkedin" class="svg-inline--fa fa-linkedin fa-w-14" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 448 512"><path fill="currentColor" d="M416 32H31.9C14.3 32 0 46.5 0 64.3v383.4C0 465.5 14.3 480 31.9 480H416c17.6 0 32-14.5 32-32.3V64.3c0-17.8-14.4-32.3-32-32.3zM135.4 416H69V202.2h66.5V416zm-33.2-243c-21.3 0-38.5-17.3-38.5-38.5S80.9 96 102.2 96c21.2 0 38.5 17.3 38.5 38.5 0 21.3-17.2 38.5-38.5 38.5zm282.1 243h-66.4V312c0-24.8-.5-56.7-34.5-56.7-34.6 0-39.9 27-39.9 54.9V416h-66.4V202.2h63.7v29.2h.9c8.9-16.8 30.6-34.5 62.9-34.5 67.2 0 79.7 44.3 79.7 101.9V416z"></path></svg></a>
          <a className="a-tag" href="https://dev.to/nathanhains"><svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" data-prefix="fab" data-icon="dev" class="svg-inline--fa fa-dev fa-w-14" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 448 512"><path fill="currentColor" d="M120.1 208.3c-3.88-2.9-7.77-4.35-11.65-4.35H91.03v104.5h17.45c3.88 0 7.77-1.45 11.65-4.35 3.88-2.9 5.82-7.25 5.82-13.06v-69.65c-.01-5.8-1.96-10.16-5.83-13.06zM404.1 32H43.9C19.7 32 .06 51.59 0 75.8v360.4C.06 460.4 19.7 480 43.9 480h360.2c24.21 0 43.84-19.59 43.9-43.8V75.8c-.06-24.21-19.7-43.8-43.9-43.8zM154.2 291.2c0 18.81-11.61 47.31-48.36 47.25h-46.4V172.1h47.38c35.44 0 47.36 28.46 47.37 47.28l.01 70.93zm100.7-88.66H201.6v38.42h32.57v29.57H201.6v38.41h53.29v29.57h-62.18c-11.16 .29-20.44-8.53-20.72-19.69V193.7c-.27-11.15 8.56-20.41 19.71-20.69h63.19l-.01 29.52zm103.6 115.3c-13.2 30.75-36.85 24.63-47.44 0l-38.53-144.8h32.57l29.71 113.7 29.57-113.7h32.58l-38.46 144.8z"></path></svg></a>
          <a className="a-tag" href="https://twitter.com/nathanhains"><svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" data-prefix="fab" data-icon="twitter-square" class="svg-inline--fa fa-twitter-square fa-w-14" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 448 512"><path fill="currentColor" d="M400 32H48C21.5 32 0 53.5 0 80v352c0 26.5 21.5 48 48 48h352c26.5 0 48-21.5 48-48V80c0-26.5-21.5-48-48-48zm-48.9 158.8c.2 2.8 .2 5.7 .2 8.5 0 86.7-66 186.6-186.6 186.6-37.2 0-71.7-10.8-100.7-29.4 5.3 .6 10.4 .8 15.8 .8 30.7 0 58.9-10.4 81.4-28-28.8-.6-53-19.5-61.3-45.5 10.1 1.5 19.2 1.5 29.6-1.2-30-6.1-52.5-32.5-52.5-64.4v-.8c8.7 4.9 18.9 7.9 29.6 8.3a65.45 65.45 0 0 1 -29.2-54.6c0-12.2 3.2-23.4 8.9-33.1 32.3 39.8 80.8 65.8 135.2 68.6-9.3-44.5 24-80.6 64-80.6 18.9 0 35.9 7.9 47.9 20.7 14.8-2.8 29-8.3 41.6-15.8-4.9 15.2-15.2 28-28.8 36.1 13.2-1.4 26-5.1 37.8-10.2-8.9 13.1-20.1 24.7-32.9 34z"></path></svg></a>
        </div>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
.medias {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1788px;
  height: 90%;
  left: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.medias-bar {
  z-index: 5;
  width: 50%;
  height: 10%;
  top: 70%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -118px;
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;

}

.medias-bar svg{
  padding: 14px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 12.7px;
  transition: 600ms;
}

.medias-bar svg:hover {
  padding: 18px;
  filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 5px rgba(235, 209, 164, 1));
}

.fa-github-square{
  filter: drop-shadow(-5px 7px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4));
}

.fa-twitter-square{
  filter: drop-shadow(5px 7px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4));
}

.fa-linkedin{
  filter: drop-shadow(0px 7px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4));
}

.fa-dev{
  filter: drop-shadow(0px 7px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4));
}

.a-tag {
  color: black;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

This was working in the past with no errors as well. I am not sure why this change has happened. Any possible ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Your positioning and sizing are both over and under specified and it's pushing the content far off the page. Here's a plain HTML/CSS version that at least renders the content visible - so you could start from here and tweak. (Added a 1px border to show where the wrapper divs are rendering)

```css
.medias {
  border: 1px red solid;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  height: 90%;
  left: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.medias-bar {
  border: 1px blue solid;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 5;
  width: 50%;
  height: 10%;
  top: 70%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -118px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.medias-bar svg{
  width: 20%;
  padding: 14px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 12.7px;
  transition: 600ms;
}

.medias-bar svg:hover {
  padding: 18px;
  filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 5px rgba(235, 209, 164, 1));
}

.fa-github-square{
  filter: drop-shadow(-5px 7px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4));
}

.fa-twitter-square{
  filter: drop-shadow(5px 7px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4));
}

.fa-linkedin{
  filter: drop-shadow(0px 7px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4));
}

.fa-dev{
  filter: drop-shadow(0px 7px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4));
}

.a-tag {
  color: black;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="medias">
        <div id="contact" class="medias-bar">
          <a class="a-tag" href="https://github.com/nathanhains"><svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" data-prefix="fab" data-icon="github-square" class="svg-inline--fa fa-github-square fa-w-14" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 448 512"><path fill="currentColor" d="M400 32H48C21.5 32 0 53.5 0 80v352c0 26.5 21.5 48 48 48h352c26.5 0 48-21.5 48-48V80c0-26.5-21.5-48-48-48zM277.3 415.7c-8.4 1.5-11.5-3.7-11.5-8 0-5.4 .2-33 .2-55.3 0-15.6-5.2-25.5-11.3-30.7 37-4.1 76-9.2 76-73.1 0-18.2-6.5-27.3-17.1-39 1.7-4.3 7.4-22-1.7-45-13.9-4.3-45.7 17.9-45.7 17.9-13.2-3.7-27.5-5.6-41.6-5.6-14.1 0-28.4 1.9-41.6 5.6 0 0-31.8-22.2-45.7-17.9-9.1 22.9-3.5 40.6-1.7 45-10.6 11.7-15.6 20.8-15.6 39 0 63.6 37.3 69 74.3 73.1-4.8 4.3-9.1 11.7-10.6 22.3-9.5 4.3-33.8 11.7-48.3-13.9-9.1-15.8-25.5-17.1-25.5-17.1-16.2-.2-1.1 10.2-1.1 10.2 10.8 5 18.4 24.2 18.4 24.2 9.7 29.7 56.1 19.7 56.1 19.7 0 13.9 .2 36.5 .2 40.6 0 4.3-3 9.5-11.5 8-66-22.1-112.2-84.9-112.2-158.3 0-91.8 70.2-161.5 162-161.5S388 165.6 388 257.4c.1 73.4-44.7 136.3-110.7 158.3zm-98.1-61.1c-1.9 .4-3.7-.4-3.9-1.7-.2-1.5 1.1-2.8 3-3.2 1.9-.2 3.7 .6 3.9 1.9 .3 1.3-1 2.6-3 3zm-9.5-.9c0 1.3-1.5 2.4-3.5 2.4-2.2 .2-3.7-.9-3.7-2.4 0-1.3 1.5-2.4 3.5-2.4 1.9-.2 3.7 .9 3.7 2.4zm-13.7-1.1c-.4 1.3-2.4 1.9-4.1 1.3-1.9-.4-3.2-1.9-2.8-3.2 .4-1.3 2.4-1.9 4.1-1.5 2 .6 3.3 2.1 2.8 3.4zm-12.3-5.4c-.9 1.1-2.8 .9-4.3-.6-1.5-1.3-1.9-3.2-.9-4.1 .9-1.1 2.8-.9 4.3 .6 1.3 1.3 1.8 3.3 .9 4.1zm-9.1-9.1c-.9 .6-2.6 0-3.7-1.5s-1.1-3.2 0-3.9c1.1-.9 2.8-.2 3.7 1.3 1.1 1.5 1.1 3.3 0 4.1zm-6.5-9.7c-.9 .9-2.4 .4-3.5-.6-1.1-1.3-1.3-2.8-.4-3.5 .9-.9 2.4-.4 3.5 .6 1.1 1.3 1.3 2.8 .4 3.5zm-6.7-7.4c-.4 .9-1.7 1.1-2.8 .4-1.3-.6-1.9-1.7-1.5-2.6 .4-.6 1.5-.9 2.8-.4 1.3 .7 1.9 1.8 1.5 2.6z"></path></svg></a>
          <a class="a-tag" href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/nathanhains/"><svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" data-prefix="fab" data-icon="linkedin" class="svg-inline--fa fa-linkedin fa-w-14" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 448 512"><path fill="currentColor" d="M416 32H31.9C14.3 32 0 46.5 0 64.3v383.4C0 465.5 14.3 480 31.9 480H416c17.6 0 32-14.5 32-32.3V64.3c0-17.8-14.4-32.3-32-32.3zM135.4 416H69V202.2h66.5V416zm-33.2-243c-21.3 0-38.5-17.3-38.5-38.5S80.9 96 102.2 96c21.2 0 38.5 17.3 38.5 38.5 0 21.3-17.2 38.5-38.5 38.5zm282.1 243h-66.4V312c0-24.8-.5-56.7-34.5-56.7-34.6 0-39.9 27-39.9 54.9V416h-66.4V202.2h63.7v29.2h.9c8.9-16.8 30.6-34.5 62.9-34.5 67.2 0 79.7 44.3 79.7 101.9V416z"></path></svg></a>
          <a class="a-tag" href="https://dev.to/nathanhains"><svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" data-prefix="fab" data-icon="dev" class="svg-inline--fa fa-dev fa-w-14" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 448 512"><path fill="currentColor" d="M120.1 208.3c-3.88-2.9-7.77-4.35-11.65-4.35H91.03v104.5h17.45c3.88 0 7.77-1.45 11.65-4.35 3.88-2.9 5.82-7.25 5.82-13.06v-69.65c-.01-5.8-1.96-10.16-5.83-13.06zM404.1 32H43.9C19.7 32 .06 51.59 0 75.8v360.4C.06 460.4 19.7 480 43.9 480h360.2c24.21 0 43.84-19.59 43.9-43.8V75.8c-.06-24.21-19.7-43.8-43.9-43.8zM154.2 291.2c0 18.81-11.61 47.31-48.36 47.25h-46.4V172.1h47.38c35.44 0 47.36 28.46 47.37 47.28l.01 70.93zm100.7-88.66H201.6v38.42h32.57v29.57H201.6v38.41h53.29v29.57h-62.18c-11.16 .29-20.44-8.53-20.72-19.69V193.7c-.27-11.15 8.56-20.41 19.71-20.69h63.19l-.01 29.52zm103.6 115.3c-13.2 30.75-36.85 24.63-47.44 0l-38.53-144.8h32.57l29.71 113.7 29.57-113.7h32.58l-38.46 144.8z"></path></svg></a>
          <a class="a-tag" href="https://twitter.com/nathanhains"><svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" data-prefix="fab" data-icon="twitter-square" class="svg-inline--fa fa-twitter-square fa-w-14" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 448 512"><path fill="currentColor" d="M400 32H48C21.5 32 0 53.5 0 80v352c0 26.5 21.5 48 48 48h352c26.5 0 48-21.5 48-48V80c0-26.5-21.5-48-48-48zm-48.9 158.8c.2 2.8 .2 5.7 .2 8.5 0 86.7-66 186.6-186.6 186.6-37.2 0-71.7-10.8-100.7-29.4 5.3 .6 10.4 .8 15.8 .8 30.7 0 58.9-10.4 81.4-28-28.8-.6-53-19.5-61.3-45.5 10.1 1.5 19.2 1.5 29.6-1.2-30-6.1-52.5-32.5-52.5-64.4v-.8c8.7 4.9 18.9 7.9 29.6 8.3a65.45 65.45 0 0 1 -29.2-54.6c0-12.2 3.2-23.4 8.9-33.1 32.3 39.8 80.8 65.8 135.2 68.6-9.3-44.5 24-80.6 64-80.6 18.9 0 35.9 7.9 47.9 20.7 14.8-2.8 29-8.3 41.6-15.8-4.9 15.2-15.2 28-28.8 36.1 13.2-1.4 26-5.1 37.8-10.2-8.9 13.1-20.1 24.7-32.9 34z"></path></svg></a>
        </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set `fill="black"` instead of `fill="currentColor"`

```html
<div className="medias">
        <div id="contact" className="medias-bar">
          <a className="a-tag" href="https://github.com/nathanhains"><svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" data-prefix="fab" data-icon="github-square" class="svg-inline--fa fa-github-square fa-w-14" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 448 512"><path fill="black" d="M400 32H48C21.5 32 0 53.5 0 80v352c0 26.5 21.5 48 48 48h352c26.5 0 48-21.5 48-48V80c0-26.5-21.5-48-48-48zM277.3 415.7c-8.4 1.5-11.5-3.7-11.5-8 0-5.4 .2-33 .2-55.3 0-15.6-5.2-25.5-11.3-30.7 37-4.1 76-9.2 76-73.1 0-18.2-6.5-27.3-17.1-39 1.7-4.3 7.4-22-1.7-45-13.9-4.3-45.7 17.9-45.7 17.9-13.2-3.7-27.5-5.6-41.6-5.6-14.1 0-28.4 1.9-41.6 5.6 0 0-31.8-22.2-45.7-17.9-9.1 22.9-3.5 40.6-1.7 45-10.6 11.7-15.6 20.8-15.6 39 0 63.6 37.3 69 74.3 73.1-4.8 4.3-9.1 11.7-10.6 22.3-9.5 4.3-33.8 11.7-48.3-13.9-9.1-15.8-25.5-17.1-25.5-17.1-16.2-.2-1.1 10.2-1.1 10.2 10.8 5 18.4 24.2 18.4 24.2 9.7 29.7 56.1 19.7 56.1 19.7 0 13.9 .2 36.5 .2 40.6 0 4.3-3 9.5-11.5 8-66-22.1-112.2-84.9-112.2-158.3 0-91.8 70.2-161.5 162-161.5S388 165.6 388 257.4c.1 73.4-44.7 136.3-110.7 158.3zm-98.1-61.1c-1.9 .4-3.7-.4-3.9-1.7-.2-1.5 1.1-2.8 3-3.2 1.9-.2 3.7 .6 3.9 1.9 .3 1.3-1 2.6-3 3zm-9.5-.9c0 1.3-1.5 2.4-3.5 2.4-2.2 .2-3.7-.9-3.7-2.4 0-1.3 1.5-2.4 3.5-2.4 1.9-.2 3.7 .9 3.7 2.4zm-13.7-1.1c-.4 1.3-2.4 1.9-4.1 1.3-1.9-.4-3.2-1.9-2.8-3.2 .4-1.3 2.4-1.9 4.1-1.5 2 .6 3.3 2.1 2.8 3.4zm-12.3-5.4c-.9 1.1-2.8 .9-4.3-.6-1.5-1.3-1.9-3.2-.9-4.1 .9-1.1 2.8-.9 4.3 .6 1.3 1.3 1.8 3.3 .9 4.1zm-9.1-9.1c-.9 .6-2.6 0-3.7-1.5s-1.1-3.2 0-3.9c1.1-.9 2.8-.2 3.7 1.3 1.1 1.5 1.1 3.3 0 4.1zm-6.5-9.7c-.9 .9-2.4 .4-3.5-.6-1.1-1.3-1.3-2.8-.4-3.5 .9-.9 2.4-.4 3.5 .6 1.1 1.3 1.3 2.8 .4 3.5zm-6.7-7.4c-.4 .9-1.7 1.1-2.8 .4-1.3-.6-1.9-1.7-1.5-2.6 .4-.6 1.5-.9 2.8-.4 1.3 .7 1.9 1.8 1.5 2.6z"></path></svg></a>
          <a className="a-tag" href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/nathanhains/"><svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" data-prefix="fab" data-icon="linkedin" class="svg-inline--fa fa-linkedin fa-w-14" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 448 512"><path fill="black" d="M416 32H31.9C14.3 32 0 46.5 0 64.3v383.4C0 465.5 14.3 480 31.9 480H416c17.6 0 32-14.5 32-32.3V64.3c0-17.8-14.4-32.3-32-32.3zM135.4 416H69V202.2h66.5V416zm-33.2-243c-21.3 0-38.5-17.3-38.5-38.5S80.9 96 102.2 96c21.2 0 38.5 17.3 38.5 38.5 0 21.3-17.2 38.5-38.5 38.5zm282.1 243h-66.4V312c0-24.8-.5-56.7-34.5-56.7-34.6 0-39.9 27-39.9 54.9V416h-66.4V202.2h63.7v29.2h.9c8.9-16.8 30.6-34.5 62.9-34.5 67.2 0 79.7 44.3 79.7 101.9V416z"></path></svg></a>
          <a className="a-tag" href="https://dev.to/nathanhains"><svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" data-prefix="fab" data-icon="dev" class="svg-inline--fa fa-dev fa-w-14" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 448 512"><path fill="black" d="M120.1 208.3c-3.88-2.9-7.77-4.35-11.65-4.35H91.03v104.5h17.45c3.88 0 7.77-1.45 11.65-4.35 3.88-2.9 5.82-7.25 5.82-13.06v-69.65c-.01-5.8-1.96-10.16-5.83-13.06zM404.1 32H43.9C19.7 32 .06 51.59 0 75.8v360.4C.06 460.4 19.7 480 43.9 480h360.2c24.21 0 43.84-19.59 43.9-43.8V75.8c-.06-24.21-19.7-43.8-43.9-43.8zM154.2 291.2c0 18.81-11.61 47.31-48.36 47.25h-46.4V172.1h47.38c35.44 0 47.36 28.46 47.37 47.28l.01 70.93zm100.7-88.66H201.6v38.42h32.57v29.57H201.6v38.41h53.29v29.57h-62.18c-11.16 .29-20.44-8.53-20.72-19.69V193.7c-.27-11.15 8.56-20.41 19.71-20.69h63.19l-.01 29.52zm103.6 115.3c-13.2 30.75-36.85 24.63-47.44 0l-38.53-144.8h32.57l29.71 113.7 29.57-113.7h32.58l-38.46 144.8z"></path></svg></a>
          <a className="a-tag" href="https://twitter.com/nathanhains"><svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" data-prefix="fab" data-icon="twitter-square" class="svg-inline--fa fa-twitter-square fa-w-14" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 448 512"><path fill="black" d="M400 32H48C21.5 32 0 53.5 0 80v352c0 26.5 21.5 48 48 48h352c26.5 0 48-21.5 48-48V80c0-26.5-21.5-48-48-48zm-48.9 158.8c.2 2.8 .2 5.7 .2 8.5 0 86.7-66 186.6-186.6 186.6-37.2 0-71.7-10.8-100.7-29.4 5.3 .6 10.4 .8 15.8 .8 30.7 0 58.9-10.4 81.4-28-28.8-.6-53-19.5-61.3-45.5 10.1 1.5 19.2 1.5 29.6-1.2-30-6.1-52.5-32.5-52.5-64.4v-.8c8.7 4.9 18.9 7.9 29.6 8.3a65.45 65.45 0 0 1 -29.2-54.6c0-12.2 3.2-23.4 8.9-33.1 32.3 39.8 80.8 65.8 135.2 68.6-9.3-44.5 24-80.6 64-80.6 18.9 0 35.9 7.9 47.9 20.7 14.8-2.8 29-8.3 41.6-15.8-4.9 15.2-15.2 28-28.8 36.1 13.2-1.4 26-5.1 37.8-10.2-8.9 13.1-20.1 24.7-32.9 34z"></path></svg></a>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: (I'm not a programmer but asking this question out of curiosity): Could you tell me what the long strings of numbers are on about (aka the value of the **d** attribute)?

Comment: Those are the drawing instructions - tells where to (m)ove the initial drawing point, draw (l)ines or (h)orizontal and (v)ertical ones, (a)rcs, (q)uadratic and (c)ubic bezier curves etc.: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths